# Use bootstrap to find the confidence intervals of the expected value for Y new, given X new

Tags: regression, machine-learning, python, confidence-interval, bootstrap

The following question is an assignemt I have and I'm stuck.

I've trained a linear regression model based on 200 observations that I randomely picked from the data. So now I have $X_{train}$ and $Y_{train}$. Then, I'm asked to pick another 100 observations, and find $E[Y_{new}|X_{new}]$, using whatever bootstrap approach I wish. I picked percintiles bootstrap because it makes the most sense to me.

So should I use the trained model or not? what I thought of doing is to randomly resample $X_{new}$ (which is a data frame) and $Y_{new}$ (just an array of labels) with replacement B times. Then resample $X_{new}$ and $Y_{new}$ to compute the mean of $Y_{new}$ given $X_{new}$ in each iteration of the loop. This way however I don't use the linear regression model, seems right to you?

I tried to apply this in python:

```
# Generate B bootstrap samples of the mean of Y-new
means = []
for _ in range(B):
    x_sample = np.random.choice(X_new, size=len(X_new), replace=True)
    y_sample = np.random.choice(Y_new, size=len(Y_new), replace=True)
    mean = np.mean(y_sample)
    means.append(mean)

lower = np.percentile(means, 100 * alpha / 2)
upper = np.percentile(means, 100 * (1 - alpha / 2))

# Print the results
print(f"95% confidence interval: [{lower:.4f}, {upper:.4f}]")
```

Is my approach right?

##### EDIT -

I did some transformation for $X_{new}$ to make it 1D as the error says. When I did that the code worked and I got `95% confidence interval: [37.4578, 42.5712]`. The problem is I don't know if I'm even allowed to do such a thing. Is it ok to make a data frame into a 1D array? and does this result make sense? shouldn't I get multiple cinfidence intervals for each $Y_{new}$ sample given it's row in $X_{new}$?